# How to do startdate and endate in bootstrap react js?

Tags: reactjs, forms, bootstrap-4, date-range

I am trying to make start date and end date in this date input that if I will select like 10/10/2019 then end date should start to select from 10/10/2019 not before 10, so I was trying but I could not implement so please guide me how to do this in react js and also disabled future date after current date here is my input date field

```html
<div className="col-sm-4">
    <div className="form-group">
        <span style={{ opacity: "0.6", fontSize: "13px" }}>To</span>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="from"
          id="startdate"
          className="form-control datepicker"
          style={{ width: "150px" }}
        />
      </div>
</div>
<div className="col-sm-4">
    <div className="form-group">
        <span style={{ opacity: "0.6", fontSize: "13px" }}>From</span>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="to"
          id="enddate"
          placeholder="Select Date"
          className="form-control datepicker"
          style={{ width: "150px" }}
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "min" property of HTML5 input type date to achieve this. Something like the code below. Please check if this serves your purpose.

The "min" property of "To Date" is set to the date selected in "from date", so that we can only select a date starting from that date and cannot select any previous dates. There is a "max" property as well for date input, which can be used for further controls.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-diffie-vley9